# How do I fix this error installing npm connect on my computer

Tags: node.js, npm

I recently installed node on my windows 8 computer and tested it and it seems to work fine. But when I try to install it I get this error

> npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.2.9200
>   npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs
>   \node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "connect"
>   npm ERR! node v0.12.4
>   npm ERR! npm  v2.10.1
>   npm ERR! code EACCES
>   npm ERR! errno EACCES
>   npm ERR! syscall connect
>
> npm ERR! Error: connect EACCES
>   npm ERR!     at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
>   npm ERR!     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1010:19)
>   npm ERR!  { [Error: connect EACCES] code: 'EACCES', errno: 'EACCES', syscall: 'c
>   onnect' }
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
>   npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!     C:\WINDOWS\system32\npm-debug.log

these are the contents of the npm-debug.log file from before I tried installing running cmd as administrator

> 0 info it worked if it ends with ok
>   1 verbose cli [ 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe',
>   1 verbose cli   'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js',
>   1 verbose cli   'install',
>   1 verbose cli   'connect' ]
>   2 info using npm@2.15.1
>   3 info using node@v4.4.3
>   4 verbose install initial load of C:\Users\owner\Desktop\Node.js\package.json
>   5 verbose readDependencies loading dependencies from
>  C:\Users\owner\Desktop\Node.js\package.json
>   6 silly cache add args [ 'connect', null ]
>   7 verbose cache add spec connect
>   8 silly cache add parsed spec Result {
>   8 silly cache add   raw: 'connect',
>   8 silly cache add   scope: null,
>   8 silly cache add   name: 'connect',
>   8 silly cache add   rawSpec: '',
>   8 silly cache add   spec: 'latest',
>   8 silly cache add   type: 'tag' }
>   9 silly addNamed connect@latest
>   10 verbose addNamed "latest" is being treated as a dist-tag for connect
>   11 info addNameTag [ 'connect', 'latest' ]
>   12 silly mapToRegistry name connect
>   13 silly mapToRegistry using default registry
>   14 silly mapToRegistry registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
>   15 silly mapToRegistry data Result {
>   15 silly mapToRegistry   raw: 'connect',
>   15 silly mapToRegistry   scope: null,
>   15 silly mapToRegistry   name: 'connect',
>   15 silly mapToRegistry   rawSpec: '',
>   15 silly mapToRegistry   spec: 'latest',
>   15 silly mapToRegistry   type: 'tag' }
>   16 silly mapToRegistry uri https://registry.npmjs.org/connect
>   17 verbose addNameTag registry:https://registry.npmjs.org/connect not in flight; fetching
>   18 verbose request uri https://registry.npmjs.org/connect
>   19 verbose request no auth needed
>   20 info attempt registry request try #1 at 11:26:28 PM
>   21 verbose request id d04b099ed5c5d169
>   22 http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/connect
>   23 info retry will retry, error on last attempt:
>  Error: connect EACCES 23.235.40.162:443
>   24 info attempt registry request try #2 at 11:26:38 PM
>   25 http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/connect
>   26 info retry will retry, error on last attempt:
>  Error: connect EACCES 23.235.39.162:443
>   27 info attempt registry request try #3 at 11:27:38 PM
>   28 http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/connect
>   29 verbose stack Error: connect EACCES 23.235.46.162:443
>   29 verbose stack     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
>   29 verbose stack     at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:893:20)
>   29 verbose stack     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1061:14)
>   30 verbose cwd C:\Users\owner\Desktop\Node.js
>   31 error Windows_NT 6.2.9200
>   32 error argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "connect"
>   33 error node v4.4.3
>   34 error npm  v2.15.1
>   35 error code EACCES
>   36 error errno EACCES
>   37 error syscall connect
>   38 error Error: connect EACCES 23.235.46.162:443
>  38 error     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
>   38 error     at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:893:20)
>   38 error     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1061:14)
>   38 error  { [Error: connect EACCES 23.235.46.162:443]
>   38 error   code: 'EACCES',
>   38 error   errno: 'EACCES',
>   38 error   syscall: 'connect',
>   38 error   address: '23.235.46.162',
>   38 error   port: 443 }
>   39 error Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
>   40 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

I have already tried running the command "npm install connect" as Administrator and got the same thing. Can anyone help?

Comment: Use unix or a vm, on another node can you paste the contents of npm-debug.log here as well :)

Comment: In which folder are you trying to install this module? According to where npm-debug.log is placed, it's system32. If that's correct, this isn't letting you install there because of obvious security reasons. Try using another folder.

Comment: @MarkoGrešak the first time I tried installing it was in a file in the desktop which didn't work, and I tried running it as administrator and that's when it tried installing in system 32.

Comment: @Sparksido if you just open the cmd as admin, it probably defaults to system32 folder. Try cding to desktop or similar before trying to install. If install works then, you should firstly look into fixing these permission issues, you shouldn't need admin privileges to install npm packages and if you ignore that, I bet you'll forget about it one time and will waste time debugging it. Happened to a friend and it took me almost an hour to figure it out.

Comment: I just changed the permissions, gave full control to users for the npm forlder but I still get the error when i try to install

Answer (score 2):

The error occurs because you probably installed Node with root permissions but you're not executing `npm` with the same permissions. Permissions you used when installing Node will be required when doing things like writing in your npm directory (npm link, npm install -g, etc.).

The recommended way to fix this is by installing [`nvm-windows`](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows) and using this to manage your Node installations. This prevents you from having to hack around the permissions on your machine.